# Remove alias from current session

Tags: alias, session

How to remove a `alias` from current session without closing that session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing that your alias to **`python`** is `py`, do:

```
$ unalias py
```

([via](http://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/working-with-aliases))